# SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17006 null

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Welcome
Why when I use my phone number to get OTP from Firebase
This problem appears to me
OTP is not sent to the phone number
Note that the phone number is from the Syrian Arab Republic
thank you very much

I try with a different phone number from the numbers of the Syrian Arab Republic, and it works normally what is the expected reason